# Perl: How Can I distribute my own package MYModule.pm?

Tags: perl, module, packaging

I have a developed my own package,i want to distribute my module like in CPAN. Want to package my MYModule.pm to be as distributed, and installable as using MakeFile.pl.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and to the Perl tag. Please take a moment to  read [ask] and take the [tour]. There is no question mark in your question. Please [edit] the question and improve it.

Comment: There are arguably easier ways now but you might find what you need here in this detailed guide: http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=431702

Answer (score 1):

```
1649  module-starter --module urModule --author="xx xxxx" --email="a.xxxx@xxx.com"
1651  cd urModule/
1653  perl Makefile.PL
1654  make
1655  make test
# test coverage
1656  cover -test
# make tar.gz
1658  make dist
# make spec file for building a rpm
1660  cpanspec DirTree-0.01.tar.gz
# get an account over pause.perl.org
```

Comment: actually you only need line 1649 to create the package, not sure this is against the rule to recommend specific tool or software.